# Difference between a pair of vectors spanning a space, and a pair of vectors being the basis vectors of a space.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**: $\bar v + \bar w$ and $\bar v - \bar w$ are combinations of $\bar v$ and $\bar w$. The two pairs of vectors span the same space. When are they a basis for the same space?

**Answer**: They are a basis when $\bar v$ and $\bar w$ are independents.

> When the pair of vectors span the same space, doesn't it immediately tell you that they are a basis for that space?

> Are these two statements different in some way? I feel that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ span $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. However, they are not a basis of that space, since they are linearly dependent.

A basis is a linearly independent set that spans the space.

Comment: So a vector to span a space would mean it lies in the space, nothing more

Comment: No. If a vector $v\ne0$ spans a space $V$, then $\dim V=1$ and every element of $V$ is of the form $\lambda v$, for some scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: Jesus, when you earned 158 gold?

Comment: @Aqua It's ridiculous. It is due to the new rules concerning review queues: a gold medal for each 1000 reviews.

Comment: I see you have already 2 new gold :)

Comment: @Aqua Indeed. From Low Quallity Posts and from Suggested edits.